# Silverlight: Navigation app template - can we have cleaner urls? And urls like asp.net MVC / Routing has?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, url-routing, silverlight-toolkit

I have just created a new silverlight app using Silverlight navigation template. All went well and its working :-)

But the url has an extension of aspx ... can we not remove like asp.net MVC has done?

```
    SilverlightApplication1TestPage.aspx
```

The next thing that i found strange is how it appends the page name, it uses # symbol like so

```
    SilverlightApplication1TestPage.aspx#Home
```

I thought it would be more natural to do this (also like asp.net mvc does)

```
     SilverlightApplication1TestPage/Home

     SilverlightApplication1TestPage/About
```

Is there a kind of work around or updated tamplete of some kind

Or its not possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THanks everyone for comments, it got me thinking... and i think i have fixed it.. and found a solutions using asp.net 4.0 routing...

Add a global file to the asp.net project and then add this to application start

```
// Code that runs on application startup
        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("SilverlightRoute",
        "MyApp",
        "~/SilverlightApplication1TestPage.aspx");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Silverlight with Asp.Net MVC and here is a sample URL: http://localhost:37920/#/AdvancedSearch.  When I was using straight Asp.Net then yeah I had .aspx files in it.  It Still isn't what you really want but gets you closer maybe.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom line is: no.  To simplify it everything in a URL prior to the # belongs to the server and everything after the # belongs to the client.

A Silverlight application exists entirely with with in a single URL (page) from the servers perspective.  When you use the Silverlight navigation framework you are moving about within the app inside this single HTML page.

If the # is removed there would be fetches made to the server and the results would replace the existing page, the current SL app will be unloaded to be replaced with the resulting content.  Even if that resulting content is the same SL app but directed to a different context it would still unload the app and reload it.

The use # is merely a means for navigation within the Silverlight app to be tracked within the browsers navigation history.  The browsers own back button will then operate in a way that doesn't surprise the user.